# Integral of complete elliptic Integral of second kind

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

I am currently wondering wether there is an indefinite integral for 
$$\int dx \;\sqrt{1-x^2} E\left (1+\frac{1}{x^2-1} \right )$$ 
*WolframAlpha* states, that there is no result in terms of analytical functions. I am not a Mathematician and don't know the current literature in the field. I wonder whether there maybe is literature more recent, which has a solution for this.

Also if there is no solution, I wonder whether there is a way to prove that there is no solution.

Looking forward to helpfull answers.

Cheers!

Comment: Since you mention Wolfram Alpha in your question, is it safe to assume you're using their definition for $E$? (Whenever asking questions about elliptic integrals, I'd suggest always including the definition in use because not all sources adopt the same one.)

Comment: Yes that is correct, thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 2):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\left[-1,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(z\right)}
&:=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\operatorname{E}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}-1}\right)},\tag{1}\\
\end{align}$$

where the complete elliptic integral of the second is defined as a function of the elliptic parameter $\mu$ by the integral representation

$$\operatorname{E}{\left(\mu\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{1-\mu x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}};~~~\small{\mu\in\left(-\infty,1\right]}.\tag{2}$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\mathcal{I}$ is a valid antiderivative over the interval $[-1,1]$. The question is whether $\mathcal{I}$ has a closed form in terms of recognizable special functions.

---

The following functional relation for $E$ is very helpful here:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}{\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)}
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}\operatorname{E}{\left(z\right)};~~~\small{z\in\left(-\infty,1\right)}.\tag{3}\\
\end{align}$$

This relation is just a special case of Pfaff's transformation for hypergeometric functions.

---

Let $z\in\left[-1,1\right]$. Using Pfaff's transformation, the integral simplifies to

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(z\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\operatorname{E}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}-1}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\operatorname{E}{\left(\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}-1}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\operatorname{E}{\left(x^{2}\right)}.\tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

Wolfram Alpha is in fact capable of returning an antiderivative for $\operatorname{E}{\left(x^{2}\right)}$ in the form of a generalized hypergeometric function (the antiderivative can also be found [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE/21/01/02/01/01/02/0005/)), giving us

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(z\right)}
&=\frac{\pi z}{2}\,{_3F_2}{\left(-\frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac32;z^{2}\right)}.\tag{5}\\
\end{align}$$

I couldn't find any known expressions for the function in the tables [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/03/08/04/02/01/), and my own attempts to derive one failed as well. So unfortunately, this hypergeometric function might be the simplest closed-form that we can find.

---